# Find the limit of $x(n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{n^3+k^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of the next series: 
$$x(n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{n^3+k^2}$$ 
I have tried using Riemann sums, but it seems it can't be solved this way.

Comment: The limit is same as $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n-n^{3/2}\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: Have you tried squeezing ?

Comment: @rpm That seems "Ramanujan-ist".  just curious, but how did you arrive at that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since:
$$ \frac{k^2}{n^3+n^2}\leq \frac{k^2}{n^3+k^2}\leq\frac{k^2}{n^3} \tag{1}$$
and:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac{n^3}{3}+O(n^2),\tag{2}$$
the limit is just $\displaystyle\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}$ by squeezing.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+n^2}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+k^2}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3}$.